# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition

Tags: php, laravel

I keep getting an error while migrating in Laravel.

What is this error?

[image: error]

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('consultation_provider', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('userId')->nullable()->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('providerId')->nullable()->constrained('users')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->foreignId('consultationId')->constrained('consultations')->cascadeOnDelete();
        $table->integer('adequacy', 10)->nullable();
        $table->integer('honesty', 10)->nullable();
        $table->integer('good_behaviour', 10)->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$table->integer()` method accept two parameters, fist one is column name, second is Boolean determine if your column is auto increment.
so , when you use:

```
 $table->integer('adequacy', 10)->nullable();
```

since 10 > 0 ,it will be:

```
$table->integer('adequacy', true)->nullable();
```

and sql table can have only one auto increment column, witch is in our case 'id'

you should remove the second argument.

```
$table->integer('adequacy')->nullable();
```

note: if you want to change your integer column type, you will find a lot of available columns integer types in [doc](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/migrations#available-column-types).